# Struggling with four square cipher decryption in python

Tags: python, cryptography

here is my codes the main program it is a hill climbing algorithm which tries to decypt a four square cipher however, this doesn#'t work may someone help

```
import random
import ngram_score2 as ns
import copy
from nltk.metrics import edit_distance
from autocorrect import Speller

spell = Speller(lang='en')

fitness = ns.ngram_score('english_trigrams.txt')

from nltk.metrics import edit_distance

crypted = input("Enter the Cipher:\n")

crypted_words = crypted.split(' ')

cipher = list(set(crypted.replace(' ', '')))
key = ['uaomhyrtcsvkbfqixnzpldwe',"uaomhyrtcsvkbfqixnzpldwe"]  


def score(key):
    points = 0
    decr = dict(zip(cipher, key))
    for word in crypted_words:
        decrypted_word = "".join([decr.get(l, '') for l in word])
        points += fitness.score(decrypted_word)
    return points


import re

# Default table
table = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
         ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
         ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
         ['P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'],
         ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]


def generate_table(key=''):
  alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ'
  table = [[''] * 5 for _ in range(5)] 

  key = re.sub(r'[\W]', '', key).upper()

  for row in range(5):
      for col in range(5):
          if len(key):
              table[row][col] = key[0]
              alphabet = alphabet.replace(key[0], '')
              key = key.replace(key[0], '')
          else:
              table[row][col] = alphabet[0]
              alphabet = alphabet[1:]
  return table



def decrypt(keys, words):
    ciphertext = ''
    words = re.sub(r'[\W]', '', words).upper().replace('Q', '')
    R, L = generate_table(key[0]), generate_table(key[1])

    for i in range(0, len(words), 2):
        digraphs = words[i:i + 2]
        ciphertext += unmangle(R, L, digraphs)
    return ciphertext.lower()


def unmangle(R, L, digraphs):
    a = position(R, digraphs[0])
    b = position(L, digraphs[1])
    return table[a[0]][b[1]] + table[b[0]][a[1]]


def position(table, ch):
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
            if table[row][col] == ch:
                return (row, col)
    return (None, None)




def shuffle(key):
    a = random.randint(0, len(key) - 1)
    b = random.randint(0, len(key) - 1)
    a_v = key[a]
    b_v = key[b]
    am = list(key)
    am[b] = a_v
    am[a] = b_v
    return "".join(am)


points = -1000000
max_points = points
t = 1.0
freezing = 0.9999

while True:
    new_key = shuffle(key)
    p = score(new_key)
    if p > points:
        if p > max_points:
            max_points = p
            print("temperature", t)
            print("POINTS", p)
            print("KEY", new_key)
            sentence = decrypt(key, crypted)
            print(sentence)
        key = new_key
        points = p
    else:
        if random.random() < t:
            points = p
            key = new_key
    t *= freezing
    if t < 0.001:
        points = p
        break
```

the ngram score code

```
'''
Allows scoring of text using n-gram probabilities
17/07/12
'''
from math import log10

class ngram_score(object):
    def __init__(self,ngramfile,sep=' '):
        ''' load a file containing ngrams and counts, calculate log probabilities '''
        self.ngrams = {}
        for line in open(ngramfile):
            key,count = line.split(sep)
            self.ngrams[key] = int(count)
            self.L = len(key)
        self.N = sum(self.ngrams.values())
        #calculate log probabilities
        for key in list(self.ngrams.keys()):
            self.ngrams[key] = log10(float(self.ngrams[key])/self.N)
        self.floor = log10(0.01/self.N)

    def score(self,text):
        ''' compute the score of text '''
        sc = 0
        ngrams = self.ngrams.__getitem__
        for i in range(len(text)-self.L+1):
            ngram = text[i:i+self.L].upper()
            #print(ngram)
            if ngram in self.ngrams: sc += ngrams(ngram)
        else: sc += self.floor

        return sc
```

IT gives me this errors say that the string range is out of index

The error you're encountering is related to the fact that in Python, when you create a list using the expression [0] * 5, it creates a list with five elements, all initialized to the value 0. However, in the context of a substitution cipher table, it seems you want to initialize the elements to be strings representing letters.

Comment: There seems to be an answer (which may or may not be correct) at the end of your question

Comment: I don't know how to implement this though